# Search Keywords SharePoint 2010 Enterprise Search

Tags: search, search-results, enterprise-search

Does the Search Keywords (/_layouts/listkeywords.aspx) with synonyms have any effect on regular search results or is it only applicable to Best Bets. For example if I have the following Keyword with synonyms: United States {USA;US}. Will a search query for US also give me documents for USA and United States, or is it only meant for Best Bets. Is this functionality different between Fast for SharePoint and Enterprise Search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience is only related to Best Bets. Not sure about Fast, as there as some improvements related to visual best bests, but cannot imagine the behavior as different.

I believe you might have this http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh133422.aspx

C:\Marius